# get java.math.BigInteger from executeInsert() using Anorm in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, anorm

The problem is that executeInsert returns the Long type result But i want the executeInsert to return the java.math.BigInteger type of result.Since, the userId in database is of 20 digit long.
Now, i am trying to parse the executeInsert result to java.math.BigInteger using ResultSetParser.
Could anyone write solution:

```
val id=SQL(
  """
    INSERT INTO registration(userId,name) 
       VALUES (1,"sam")
  """
).executeInsert();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.!! I found the solution. It works:

```
val id=SQL(
  """
INSERT INTO registration(userId,name) 
   VALUES (1,"sam")
  """
).executeInsert(scalar[BigInteger].single);
```